# artefacts by applying textures on cylinder with subdivision surfacing

Tags: texturing, uv, subdivision-surface

For educational purposes I am trying to unwrap a part of a cylinder (using blender 2.93.7), and I have the following problem:

I have this cylinder (I marked the seams to make other tests but we will not need)
[image]

I unwrapped it with cylinder projection like this:
[image]

then I apply a subdivision surface to the cylinder and on the seam I get artifacts like this:
[image]

I can't figure out what the reason is, also because all the faces in that set should be quads. What do I need to do to fix this?

I attach the [project](https://www.mediafire.com/file/md3t5uuxfbgckqn/proveblender.zip/file) with the texture

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your *Subdivision Surface* advanced settings, choose *UV Smooth > Keep Corners*:

[image]